# Some values turning to NAN after applying pd.to_numeric

Tags: python, pandas

Original data_set_example[image]

using this command:

```
pd.to_numeric(
df_rental['by_day'].str.replace('$', ''), errors='coerce')
```

Some values in the select column are turning nan using the above command with or without `.str.replace('$', '')

How should I change '-' to zero and basically change the displayed columns from object to numeric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here're my take:

- `$` is a special regex character indicating end-of-string, you need `.str.replace('\$', '')`.
- The `errors='coerce'` option will replace `-` with `nan`. If you want, you can `.fillna(0)` after conversion; or you can do `.str.replace('\$','').replace('-', '0')` before conversion.
- Also, please do not include your data as images, include as text.

Comment: Your answer worked but still facing issues with values in thousands, is there anything additional I need to do for those ?

Comment: @FalloutATS21 `.str.replace(',', '.')` would do.